# Laravel - how to get the last row id that will create in the future

Tags: laravel

I want to insert a simple menu in my database, and the menu also supports a thumbnail. Before I insert the menu in my database, I want to grab the last incremented id(that was unknown) from MySQL for naming my thumbnail with the unique id.

I can grab the last id if the table has at least one row.

```php
// last insert id
$last_id = App\Menu::get()->last()->id;

// or // last insert id
$last_id = App\Menu::selectRaw('MAX(id) AS latest_id')->get();
```

If there is no data, then the above code should return null. My question is how can I get the last auto incremented id that will be generated by MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, change your strategy. The better way is to name your thumbnail after getting the last insert id. As you know PHP is a request base language and if you will have several requests which want to do this job at the same time you would encounter serious problems with conflict ids.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ajafari.

The better approach is to create the menu first and then name the thumbnail.

It looks like this:

```
$menu = new Menu(['column_name' => value, etc ...]);
$menu->save();
//Now you have access to the latest id of the menu in $menu->id
```

Hope that helps!